# Java - Why I'm getting this weird answer in summing double type

Tags: java, scala, jvm

Why I'm getting this weird answer?
35458.450000000004  instead of 35458.45
using java6,7 & 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] as = new double[]{ 1000.0, 1174.0, 1000.0, 2131.0, 240.0,
      390.0, 21524.15, 6426.5, 1272.8, 100.0, 200.0};

    double v = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
        v += as[i];
    }

    System.out.println(v);
}
```

In Scala (same):

```
    scala> val as = List(1000.0, 1174.0, 1000.0, 2131.0, 240.0, 390.0, 21524.15, 6426.5, 1272.8, 100.0, 200.0 );
    scala> as.sum
    res3: Double = 35458.450000000004
```

Comment: `Double` is not infinitely percise, if you need percise decimal calculations consider opting for `BigDecimal` class instead of `Double`

Comment: Just read http://floating-point-gui.de/.

Comment: This exact question has been asked seemingly a million times. Please at least do a search first before posting a question.

Comment: See also: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 1):

`double` and `float` are influenced by the internal binary representation, when converted to decimal representation.

If you need to have arbitrary precision arithmetic you need to use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> Immutable, **arbitrary-precision** signed decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Its the type you are using. Use `BigDecimal`